# Split string on },{

Tags: java, regex

I would like to split the string on "},{" even after escaping the } or { or "," it is giving me the error, can anyone let me know how to achieve this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Help us help you - share the code and the error

Comment: It might be more helpful to know what the source of the string is, and why it is formatted containing `"},{"`, it might be easier to fix the formatting from the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape second "}" like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "John},{Doe},{Anna";
    String[] parts = input.split("},\\{"); // '\\{' does the trick

    for (String part : parts){
      System.out.println(part);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
John
Doe
Anna
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all regex metacharacters (in this case $, { and }) (try using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String) ) or use a different method that substitutes a string for a string, not a regex for a string.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        String str = "Test},{check";
        String arr[] = str.split("},\\{");
        System.out.println(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `\\}` is redundant and also there is a typo in `\\}'\\{`. Should be `\\},\\{`

Answer (score 0):

You can quote the metacharacters "by hand"; this makes your code more difficult to read, though.

An alternative way to do this is to use `Pattern.quote`:

```
str.split(Pattern.quote("},{"))
```

This allows you to keep the literal pattern you want to split on in the source code.